# Free Ruby scheduled tasks (off the rails) hosting?

Tags: ruby, cloud-hosting

I have some simple Ruby scripts to run as a background job. They are in an infinite while loop to monitor external database changes.  Can someone recommend a hosting provider that can do it for free to start?

I looked at AWS and the EC2 micro instance is actually a good fit for the first year.  Anything equivalent beyond the first year?

Then I looked at Heroku.  It seems a hack and overkill to use Delayed Job in the Rails framework.

Google App Engine is also a good fit as long as I am willing to rewrite my Ruby scripts to Python.

More background on my project. I am using CouchDB + CouchApp.  It requires some external scripts to monitor new users sign up and send out forget password emails.

Comment: Now that the new Heroku stack is out and supports [Procfile](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) (allowing you to run any kind of process you want, not just DelayedJob), you might be able to get a process running there that isn't part of a full Rails app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you able to set up an always on machine at your house? It's probably going to be just as reliable as hosting it with a free tier provider.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about free, but there is [SimpleWorker](http://www.simpleworker.com/), which lets you offload processes (and apparently schedule them too!) to their cloud infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://callmyapp.com